# Where to find LieSymm-PDE Package for Mathematica?

Tags: differential-equations, packages

I am unable to find the *LieSymm-PDE* package for Mathematica developed by Vladimir Pulov et al as outlined on the website: http://www.swmath.org/software/12188 as well as explained in the paper: https://www.emis.de/proceedings/Varna/vol9/Pulov.pdf. It seems to be very useful to determine the Lie Algebra corresponding to a general coupled system of linear partial differential equations.

Comment: Have you tried contacting the author?

Comment: @Szabolcs I have sent the author a mail asking for access. The fact that some book has mentioned the use of his package for computations, made me believe that it must be a free access one.

Comment: @Szabolcs I also need LieSymm-PDE package for Mathematica developed by Vladimir Pulov et al as outlined on the website: http://www.swmath.org/software/12188 as well. Kindly let me know how to access it too.